# Is there any way to inherit the existing TLD definition for particular JSP Tag?

Tags: jsp, tags

I am planning to extend the basic html input tag provided by Spring to incorporate more features into it. I did similar kind of exercise in past for Struts too. At that point of time I had to create a tld file with the attributes that I introduced plus all the attributes available in the parent tag.

This is bit tiresome and repetitive so the question is that Is there anyway to inherit the existing TLD definition for particular JSP Tag?

Or any shortcut?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is an option to **inherit** a TLD definition.

The shortest solution, i think, will be to inherit the tag class and change the tld to your new (derived) class.